# Gridpane positioning in Java Fx

Tags: javafx-2

I am new to Java Fx using Netbeans 7.3.1.I am experimenting new things with Gridpane and I just want to place a Gridpane in a another position other than the left topmost position of the window..The `root.getChildren().add(gridpane);` adds the gridpane to the topmost left corner of the window.. How can i place the Gridpane on another place of the window without adding any new child or root!!My root is just a group and the current code just overlaps the gridpane with the Menubar.. My full code is this!!

```
public class Menu extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    javafx.scene.control.Menu m = new javafx.scene.control.Menu("File");
    m.getItems().add(new MenuItem("New"));
    m.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());
    m.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Exit"));
    menuBar.getMenus().add(m);
    javafx.scene.control.Menu tools = new javafx.scene.control.Menu("Cameras");
    tools.getItems().add(CheckMenuItemBuilder.create()
    .text("Show Camera 1")
    .selected(false)
    .build());
    menuBar.getMenus().add(tools);
    root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
    GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
    gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
    gridpane.setHgap(5);
    gridpane.setVgap(5);
    Label fNameLbl = new Label("First Name");
    TextField fNameFld = new TextField();
    Label lNameLbl = new Label("First Name");
    TextField lNameFld = new TextField();
    Button saveButt = new Button("Save");
    // First name label
    GridPane.setHalignment(fNameLbl, HPos.RIGHT);
    gridpane.add(fNameLbl, 0, 0);
    // Last name label
    GridPane.setHalignment(lNameLbl, HPos.RIGHT);
    gridpane.add(lNameLbl, 0, 1);
    // First name field
    GridPane.setHalignment(fNameFld, HPos.LEFT);
    gridpane.add(fNameFld, 1, 0);
    // Last name field
    GridPane.setHalignment(lNameFld, HPos.LEFT);
    gridpane.add(lNameFld, 1, 1);
    // Save button
    GridPane.setHalignment(saveButt, HPos.RIGHT);
    gridpane.add(saveButt, 1, 2);
    root.getChildren().add(gridpane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Instead of a plain group as a root, you can use [one of the built in layout panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm), for example a VBox.

Comment: Thank you assylias for the above website!!It solved the overlapping problem!!

Answer (score 0):

try [Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html)...it is used for designing javafx pages...

you can design all your pages according you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works but try using the following:
**grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);**
Centre can be replaced with any other position as far as I am aware. I hope this helps somewhat.